# Retrieve pagination loop in SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I wrote teh following script to get data from a data extension and then process it. I than noticed that it only gets 2500 records. I read somewhere that I need to add a pagination loop, but I couldn't find any examples how this should look.As I am still learning JavaScript, could I please ask for your assistance in adding this pagination loop.

Thank you

```
<script runat="server"> 

var DE = DataExtension.Init("894D9624-9313-420D-3400-74655397D00E"); 
var data = DE.Rows.Retrieve();  

//Write(Stringify(data));   

if(data.length >= 1) { 
      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 

        ...do stuff...

    } 
} 
else { 
Write("no data to retrieve"); 
}  

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge the built-in Core library functions cannot be paginated, but the API call (which is essentially what the function is anyway) can.  And even better, you can transform it into [WSProxy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_advanced_retrieve.htm) making it even easier AND faster.

Below is an example of pagination utilizing WSProxy: (I updated it from the sample on the page to instead aim at a Data Extension.)

```
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy(),
    objectType = "DataExtensionObject[" + deCustKey + "]",
    cols = ["FirstName","LastName",etc...],
    moreData = true,
    reqID = null,
    numItems = 0;

while(moreData) {
    moreData = false;
    var data = reqID == null ?
           prox.retrieve(objectType, cols) :
           prox.getNextBatch(objectType, reqID);

    if(data != null) {
        moreData = data.HasMoreRows;
        reqID = data.RequestID;
        if(data && data.Results) {
            for(var i=0; i< data.Results.length; i++) {
                Platform.Response.Write(data.Results[i].Name);
                numItems++;
            }
        }
    }
}
Platform.Response.Write("<br />" + numItems + " total " + objectType);
```

One thing different from the Core library function is that you will need to list all of the columns you want retrieved from the call inside the `cols` array or they will be returned as empty/null.

Another option, if you can utilize AMPscript instead of SSJS, is to use a LookupOrderedRows function using DataExtensionRowCount() as the 'max records returned' value.

E.g. `SET @Rows = LookupOrderedRows(@YourDE, DataExtensionRowCount(@YourDE),"SortableAttribute asc", "FlagField", "Value")`

Now this would require some sort of flag or lookup value to work, which could be a dealbreaker. I usually solve this by having an extra field in my DEs named 'LU' which has a default value of `1`. This way if I ever need to pull every record, I can still use the LookupOrderedRows function, filtering on `..."LU", 1...` and it will return everything.