# Deleting big amount of records from a large sendable data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs, delete

I have a big sendable data extension (hundreds of millions records) in marketing cloud that has multiple primary keys.  The DE is live, and new records are being written constantly.

I need to delete some records by referencing a date attribute within the data extension, for the records that are over a certain amount of days will need to get deleted, let's say 30 days for example.

I need to run a deletion script in marketing cloud but the only approach I can think of is to match a certain filter using SSJS in a DE irrespective of the primary key. However, I think this approach has the limitations of 2500 rows and I am not sure if it is possible to customize the code to handle more and how.

I am still developing my SSJS knowledge, I will be very grateful for a low-level solution, but any suggestions of what would be the best approach to handle this will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you look at whether [data retention policy](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cab_manage_data_retention_policy.htm&type=5) might be relevant for your use case?

Comment: +1 what Lukas said, or if it’s just a one-off then see if this helps: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/289844/retrieve-pagination-loop-in-ssjs

Comment: Hi @LukasLunow and zuzannamj,  thanks. I have the retention policy applied to the DE, but before it kicks in, I will need to complete a one-off deletion. Unfortunately, the retention policy won't be a solution for the current situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion will be to add an additional field (e.g. toBeDeleted - boolean) to the DE, and populate it with a Query Activity, which sets it to true for records matching your deletion criteria.

Then you will be ale to apply the [DeleteData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_platformDataExtensionDeleteData.html) SSJS function, where you will target the rows where this field is set to True:

```javascript
<script runat="server">
     var rows = Platform.Function.DeleteData('YourDataExtension',['toBeDeleted'],['true']);
</script>
```

Comment: Seems like this our best solution. Thank you very much @lukas, this is very helpful. I will give it a try :)